# prove that this function is continuous on $[0,\infty]$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Denote by $\lambda$ the Lebesgue measure on $[-\infty,\infty]$, and let $E$ be a $\lambda$-measurable subset of $(0,\infty)$.  Define the function $f:[0,\infty]\to[0,\infty]$ by the rule
$$f(x)=\lambda\{y\in E:y\leq x\}$$
It is clear that $f$ is monotone with $f(0)=0$ and $f(\infty)=\lambda(E)$.  I want to show that $f[0,\infty]=[0,\lambda(E)]$.  Since the continuous image of a connected space is itself connected, it suffices to prove that $f$ is continuous.  However, the proof eludes me.  It seems like it should be easy, but I just can't make it work.

Perhaps it is not true after all?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For $x_1<x_2$, $f(x_2)-f(x_1)=\lambda\{y\in E:x_1<y\leq x_2\}\leq \lambda((x_1,x_2])=x_2-x_1.$ Hence $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|\leq |x_1-x_2|$ for any $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^+.$ So, $f$ is continuous on any $x\in\mathbb{R}.$

Continuty at $\infty$ can be shown using continuty of measure. For any sequence $x_n\rightarrow \infty,$ $f(x_n)=\lambda(E\cap [0,x_n])\rightarrow\lambda(E),$ because $E\cap[0,x_n]\uparrow E.$

Similarly conctinuty at zero can be shown as for any sequence $x_n\downarrow0, E\cap[0,x_n]\downarrow E\cup\{0\}=\phi\Rightarrow f(x_n)=\lambda(E\cap[0,x_n])\downarrow 0.$

Comment: Isn't Lipschitz continuity a property of functions between metric spaces?  But $[0,\infty]$, while metrizable, does not admit a metric compatible with the usual metric on $[0,\infty)$.  In particular, $f(x_2)-f(x_1)$ is not generally the distance between $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$.